# How to update parameter values through code in XtraReport devexpress using Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have 3 parameters:

1. Date From
2. Date To
3. StoreID

`StoreID` is optional, user may choose any value of they will not choose any value.

I already create a stored procedure with `@StoreID = null`, I used condition like below

```
where (StoreID = @StoreID or @StoreID is null)
```

If user don't pass any value on the parameter, it has to return all the records.

I tried this code on report

```
private void XtraSalesReport_DataSourceDemanded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = (this.Parameters["prStoreID"].Value as IList).Count;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        this.Parameters["prStoreID"].Value = null;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

I am using DevExpress 17.2

Comment: What kind of thing doesn't work? Please explain in detail & include important parts so that your problem can be easily reproduced.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto my custom parameter is working when I submit the button. But when i do drill down on the group,it is showing nothing.